Is it possible to have more than 1 parallel validator account connected to a node?
In the context of validators and block production what is the maximum number of validator accounts associated to the same instance of a polkadot node? In other words how many accounts can (should) add their session keys to the host and then send the setKeys and validate extrinsics?
Considering that the runtime provides a consensus message with one authority (account/validator) per slot that is chosen to produce a block I do not see an issue with multiple parallel validators being associated to the same node. Please correct me if I am wrong.

That depends on the mechanism being used to select collators. If using the typical collator-selection pallet from cumulus, you can simply register as many keys as the session pallet lets you and create as many accounts as you want, either as invulnerables (if you have sudo/governance) or simply candidates. The collator-selection pallet will choose a subset of them for collating for each session, and kick those that did not produce sufficient blocks.
